# Selenium Webdriver - how to apply explicit wait in table (in the for loop) using java

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

from the table each row collect the td[3] value, below is my java source code

```
WebElement biboSection = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='Label1']/div/table[2]/tbody"));
List<WebElement>rowsCount = biboSection.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
for (int k =1;k<=rowsCount.size();k++){
     String biblioTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='Label1']/div/table[2]/tbody/tr["+k+"]/td[3]")).getText().trim();
}
```

problem is if any one of the row `td[3]` tag not available, so its becomes failed, getting the below error

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='Label1']/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]"}
```

In general -  single element we can use explicit wait to avoid the above exception, but in table how can i continue with rest of the rows if particular tab not available  (i.e if `tr[5]/td[3]` not available then move to next set `tr[6]/td[3]`)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, you need to return a value when you get a NoSuchElementException. The risk of this is, you can get a false positive, so you need to make sure you do something with the exception.

What you could do is, you could take the string biblioTable elsewhere, allowing you to check for the element first. Try the following (I'm typing this without IDE, so excuse any mistakes etc):

```
var el;
String exception;
for (int k =1;k<=rowsCount.size();k++){

try
{
   el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='Label1']/div/table[2]/tbody/tr["+k+"]/td[3]"));
   return el;
}
catch (NoSuchElementException)
{
   exception = "Whatever you want"
   return exception;
}
if(exception == "Whatever you want")
{
   Console.Writeline.....
}
else{
String biblioTable = el.getText().trim();
}
}
```

So what you are doing is:
First you are creating a var and a string which you are going to return in your try/catch. Then in the try/catch, you are first going to try to return the webelement el. If you get a NoSuchElementException, you are going to return the string exception with a value, which you are going to use as a condition to create the string biblioTable. If its filled, it means that the webelement el was not there. So you can do whatever else you want and end the loop. Else, you can create the string biblioTable.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you have a typo in two places: your xpath is missing the open square bracket "[" after "//*"

Secondly, I think you can accomplish what you want with one declaration:

```
List<WebELement> biblioTable = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='Label1']/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]"));
```

Then you can access the text elements via:

```
for (WebElement text : biblioTable)
    String name = text.getText();
```